# Orbits of points in compact metric space when there exists a point that is fixed by all isometries

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, isometry

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space and Iso$(X,d)$ be a set of all isometries $f : X \rightarrow X$.

For $x \in X$ orbit of $x$ is defined as: $$\operatorname{Orb}(x) := \{f(x) : f \in \operatorname{Iso}(X,d)\}.$$

Suppose $\operatorname{Iso}(X,d)$ is infinite and suppose there is a point $x_0 \in X$ such that $f(x_0) = x_0$, for every $f \in \operatorname{Iso}(X,d)$.

Let $x$ be a point in $X$ and define $r_x := d(x_0, x)$. Let $y \in \operatorname{Orb}(x)$ and  $f \in \operatorname{Iso}(X,d)$ such that $f(x) = y$, we have $$r_x = d(x, x_0) = d(f(x), f(x_0)) = d(y, x_0).$$ It follows that $\operatorname{Orb}(x) \subseteq S(x_0, r_x)$, for every $x \in X$, where $S(x, r) := \{y \in X : d(x, y) = r\}$.

Is it maybe true that $\operatorname{Orb}(x) = S(x_0, r_x)$, for all $x \in X$, under these assumptions?

Comment: Two remarks that may improve readability: Your sentence "let $y\in $Orb$(x)$ and ..." should really be "let $y\in$Orb$(x)$, *then* ..." The distinction is small, but as of now it reads as one long assumption, but you do not mean to assume that entire sentence, and interpreted as such, the assumption is too strong to conclude the subset inclusion, but it was still obvious that the proof was correct. The second point, you need not consider $X\setminus \{x_0\}$ since the statement is automatically true for any such $x_0$

Comment: True, I edited the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the union of the unit disk in $\Bbb R^2\subset\Bbb R^3$ and the unit sphere in $\Bbb R^3$, centered at the origin (so the disk's boundary is an equator). The isometry group should be the orthogonal group $\mathrm{O}(2)$ (the $2$D reflections across lines achieved by $180^\circ$ $3$D rotations around them), with fixed point the origin, but the unit sphere is more than just one orbit.

Comment: Thank you, seems like a good counter-example.

Answer (score 2):

There is a counterexample with only 4 points, let

$$ X= \{(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,0.9)\} $$ endowed with the subspace metric from $\mathbb{R}^2$. (Draw this out, it is a slightly asymmetric square, almost like the unit square with its $(1,1)$ vertex slid down a bit)

Then the only isometry is the identity (the only contender for an isometry needs to permute the points $(0,0), (0,1)$ and $(1,0)$, by hand you can verify that none but the identity permutation can be isometrically completed) and thus the orbit of every element is the singleton containing itself, even though there are $2$ distinct points in $S((0,0),1)$.

We can turn this into a counterexample with an infinite isometry group:
replace the vertex $(0,1)$ with a copy of the sphere $U$ with radius $\frac{1}{100}$ setting for every $y\in U$, and $x\in X\setminus \{(0,1)\}$

$$d(x,y) = d(x,(0,1))$$

Then any isometry effects only the elements of $U$, so $(1,0)\notin \mbox{Orb}(y)$ for every $y\in U$ even though
$$(1,0) \in S((0,0),1) = S((0,0),d((0,0),y))$$

As an aside, when trying to answer this question, I convinced myself that there needs to be more than one element with a singleton orbit for a counterexample to work, perhaps you can try and see if this is sufficient.

Comment: This would be a counter example, but we assume X has infinitely many isometries.

Comment: I missed this, sorry

Comment: @Goki, it has now been fixed, I believe the fact that it was fixable captures some of the essence of the problem, the infinite isometry restriction plays only an artificial role

Comment: Im not sure what is an exact metric space you are mentionig, but if I'm getting it right than it seems to me its not compact.

Comment: @Goki, it should be fine now, but the counterexample is no longer elegant